# how to compare password with salted hashed password

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, security

i have a mysql table user with two field username varchar() and password salted hashed md5 28 bytes / "128 bites" -
asp.net web form with textbox 1 "user" w textbox2 "password"

how can i compare the password entered by the client in textbox2  is the same in user table 
for validation

this is my simple authenticate function i need to change code to compare password with the hashed 1

```
Public Function Authenticate(ByVal id As String, ByVal pas As String) As Integer

    Dim strConnectionString As String = ("Data Source=localhost;port=3306;Database=transfer;User ID=root;Password=password;Convert Zero Datetime=True")
    Dim instsqlconnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(strConnectionString)

    instsqlconnection.Open()

    Dim daAuthors As New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * From login_detail", instsqlconnection)
    dsPubs = New DataSet("Employee")
    daAuthors.Fill(dsPubs, "login")
    instsqlconnection.Close()


    Dim drResult As DataRow() = dsPubs.Tables("login").Select(" login_id = '" + id.ToString() + "'")

    If (drResult.Length > 0) Then
        If drResult(0)("password").ToString().Trim() = pas Then

            Return 1
        Else
            Return 2
        End If

    Else
        Return 0
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: how does the password get hashed when it is first added to the db? you need to do the same operation on the entered password to get the same hash

Comment: first 12 hexadecimal numbers (24 chars) are the salt (randomized)
 later 16 hexadecimal numbers (32 chars) are the salted md5 hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has an md5 function.  You can do the following presuming that the field for salt is called *salt*:

```
select 1 from login_detail where login_id = @yourloginId and Password = MD5(salt + @password);
```

**Important**

MD5 is not a secure method for storing passwords.  Even if salted, MD5 is known to be insecure and can be quickly broken.  You should use a secure algorithm such as BCrypt, SCrypt or PBKDF2.  These algorithms are ideal for password storage since they use salt and are slow, making rainbow table generation much more difficult.

You can upgrade your existing scheme by performing one of the above algorithms over the hash you already have.

BCrypt(MD5(salt+password)) when the user logs in you simply select the password, you then store a password version in the table and set it to 1.

```
SELECT * FROM login_detail WHERE login_id = @username

hashed = drResult(0)("password")
version = drResult(0)("version")
salt = drResult(0)("salt")

if(version = 1) then
   password = MD5(salt + password)
end if

if(Bcrypt.Verify(password,hashed))
   if(version = 1) then
        Update password = BCrypt(password), version = 2 WHERE login_id = @username
   end if

   return true
End If

return false
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to convert the password to `md5` which is enter by user. Once you convert the password from `string` to `md5 string`

You can simple call this query

```
Select 1 from login_detail ld where ld.login_id = @yourloginId and ld.Password = @md5Password;
```

Comment: thanks now i just understand the logic to start working on it

Comment: Good. If my answer solve your problem then you can accept it as answer.